# How to edit BATCH start command to start a file in folder above

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exe

I got folder with HTM offline files for my customers as a benefit. And the contain is like this:

```
Files (folder)   (with Plus.htm)
Autorun.inf
Icon.ico
START_THIS.bat
```

In Files folder are HTM files and downlodables and everything... I would like to edit BATCH file to run ONE .htm file in the "Files" folder. I am able to do that if I got the .htm file in SAME folder as batch, but I wasn't able to edit it to run it in folder above batch.

My batch file as it is now (and as it worked with .htm in same folder):

```
@echo Starting CD now...
@start Plus.htm
@cls
@exit
```

I tried to edit it so it would work with my folder structure:

```
@echo Starting CD now...
@CD "Files"
@start Plus.htm
@cls
@exit
```

But this doesn'T worked an I got this error:

> '\kostka\install\Ostatni\Marketing\Plus\DVD\Inventor Plus 2016'
>   CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC
>   paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory. Starting CD
>   now... The system cannot find the path specidied.

Any help please? I tried to think anither way for customers to have only one exe file but this is only way that I fot so far :( 
Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`start %~dp0\Files\Plus.htm`

`%dp0` expands to the directory the batch file is in